Interpert the bytes of a float as an int in glsl?
Ive gota float my_float; in my shader.
I need to interpret its bytes as an int.
I believe their is a function for this in glsl called floatBitsToInt, but apparently my version of glsl doesnt have it.
Nor does my version seem to have any bit manipulation operators.
Is there any way I can get GLSL to treat the float as an int?
Keep in mind I dont want to cast it to an int. I want to treat the existing bytes as though they are an int.
I guess what Im asking is there some way to do something like this but without the bit manipulation operators
int floatToBits(float value) {
    // Assuming 32-bit floats
    int intValue = int(value); // Cast to int (this is not what you want, but it's a starting point)
    int signBit = intValue >> 31; // Extract the sign bit (0 for positive, 1 for negative)
    int exponentBits = (intValue >> 23) & 0xFF; // Extract the exponent bits
    int mantissaBits = intValue & 0x7FFFFF; // Extract the mantissa bits

    // Combine the extracted bits into a single int
    int result = (signBit << 31) | (exponentBits << 23) | mantissaBits;
    return result;
}


Builtin functions floatBitsToInt and floatBitsToUint should do what you want

Per the specs, this is a built-in function since #version 330. Is there a reason you want to stick with an older version (or are unable to change it)?

Starting from 3.30 you can use floatBitsToInt:
int intValue = floatBitsToInt(value);

to convert the bits in the float value directly to an int without doing a conversion.

Dunno what this got a -1, here, take +1 :-)
